# Check an image if existing already in the folder before uploading - Codeginiter

Tags: image, codeigniter, uploading, file-exists

Do you have any sample codes or functions to check if an image name is existing already in the folder before uploading?
I've tried using file_exists() but it doesn't work, here is my sample code:

```
$path = FCPATH . "images2/";
$filename=$_FILE['userfile'];
$full_path = $path .$filename;
if(file_exists($filename))
{
///display error message///
}
```

Comment: what do you mean if exists? If the file *WAS* uploaded? Or if it is in a folder? Also `doesn't work` is the worst description, show errors, show log, etc;

Comment: @Jakub - to check if the file or specifically the file name of the image is already existing in the folder.

Comment: if you think you might need to accomodate similar names you can always add something like a random 4 digit string to the file name as part of the upload / save process.

Comment: try to insert the filename in your database and easy to check in there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are not getting the correct result with `file_exists()` because you don't include the full path (even tho you define it).

Try using the following: `file_exists($full_path)`

Also consider using some CI helper functions for handling files like images, or uploads. They are there to make this 'easier'.

**File helper:**
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/file_helper.html

Comment: Still getting eror:
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: _FILE

Comment: THANKS I've fixed it by  updating:
$filename=$_FILES['userfile']
to
$filename=$_FILES['userfile']['name'];

Comment: NP, check out the guide, CI has a ton of helper function to make image manipulation easier.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simplest way to check if a file exist:

```
if(is_file($filename){
    return true; //the file exist
}else{
    return false; //the file does not exist
}
```